# Score-based rating system

Tags: analysis, statistics, estimation

I am looking for a rating system to rate people based on their score on a competition and their previous rating.

[Codeforces](http://codeforces.com/) is using a variant of [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) which is pretty cool (you can read about it [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/20762?locale=en)), but it is rating people by their "rank", not their "score".

Has anyone encountered such a system?